# How many strictly descending numbers

Tags: combinatorics

How many strictly descending numbers can be formed? For example: 643, 987632, 43, 1, .... but not 4332 or 984331. The largerst strictly descending number is 9876543210.  I hope I made clear what I mean with strictly descending numbers.  I would think there are 10^2 -1 possible numbers. Since the set of these numbers is basically the Powerset of {0,1,2,...,9}.  Can someone confirm this is correct?
thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds correct.

Comment: The number of elements in the power set is $2^{10}$, not $10^2$.

Comment: Answer is wrong. It should be $2^{10}$.

Comment: of course, typo

Answer (score 3):

The number of strictly descending numbers of length $k$ is the number of ways we can select $k$ numbers from the string $9876543210$.  For instance, the number $983$ corresponds to the selection $\color{blue}{98}765\color{blue}{3}21$.  Hence, the number of strictly descending numbers of length $k$ is $\binom{10}{k}$.  Therefore, the number of strictly descending numbers is 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \binom{10}{k} = 2^{10} - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The number of strictly descending numbers of length $m$ is the number of ways we can select $m$ numbers from the numbers $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)$ since for every such choice, the arrangement is fixed. Hence, the number of strictly descending numbers of length $r$ is $$\binom{10}{r}$$  Therefore, the number of strictly descending numbers is 
$$\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4}+....\binom{10}{10}=\sum_{r = 1}^{10} \binom{10}{r} = 2^{10} - 1$$